# How to stop VS Code from opening the Panel automatically upon startup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vs-code-settings

Whenever I launch VSCode (either using the terminal or desktop icon) on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, it automatically opens the *Panel* at the bottom:

[image: VSCode Panel (upon startup)]

How do I stop that? Of course, I can manually close that every time I open the VSCode. But that's kind of annoying. So, I was wondering if there are any options in the settings.

Comment: does this happen even if you start VS Code from commandline like `code --disable extensions <workspace-folder-path>` ?

Comment: Yup, it still happens. It still opens the panel. I also get this warning in the terminal: `Warning: 'disable' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.`

Comment: ah shoot. I meant `--disable-extensions` can you try that?

Comment: @starball Thanks. Yes, if I use the `--disable-extensions` argument, it does not open the _Panel_. However, it is not a feasible option as I will not be able to leverage any of the installed extensions!

Comment: then it sounds like it's caused by an extension. try starting VS Code with only one extension enabled at a time and figure out which one is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings, you can search for `Auto Open Output Window On Restore` and set the value to `false` if it isn't already.  `ctrl + ,` on Windows, or `command + ,` on Mac[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, I don't see that option (at least not on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine)

Answer (score 0):

It remembers what panel was open the last time you closed that workspace folder / VS Code and restores that workbench state when reopening the workspace folder. As far as I know, at the time of this writing, there's no built-in way to disable this.

The one exception I know of is the terminal panel, which has the `terminal.integrated.hideOnStartup` setting.

In general, that state is stored in the state database for that workspace folder (which is stored in [the user-data directory](/q/70396384/11107541) at `./User/workspaceStorage/<workspace-hash>/state.vscdb`). It's an SQLite database, and the specific entry storing it is `workbench.panel.hidden` (see also `workbench.panelpart.activepanelid`). So there are technically things you can do to automate flipping that, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort. If you want a setting that controls this, then you can [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md). Some of the related code is in [src/vs/workbench/browser/layout.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d6fb91c889af15e5c9eece516ab520798da33c66/src/vs/workbench/browser/layout.ts#L693).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in my case, the Panel tab pops up even when I close it before closing the VS Code and reopening it. 
I tried playing with the `terminal.integrated.hideOnStartup` setting but it didn't help.